# Unable to get bluestack downloaded data

Tags: sd-card, windows, file-transfer, bluestacks

I installed Bluestacks and  I am trying to access files downloaded via Bluestacks but I seem not to find these files (folder is empty). I have also installed ES file explorer . Can anyone provide a  good solution on how to access these files ?

Comment: You mean download folder?

Comment: You might also wish to see [How to transfer files between BlueStacks and Windows PC](/q/105503/16575) for related answers.

Answer (score 4):

My path to shared data is
`C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\Engine\UserData\SharedFolder`

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for the update! It is indeed the path for newer versions of windows specifically Win 10. In older versions it was just `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder`

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice [tutorial explaining how to do this](http://howdygeeks.com/transfer-files-images-bluestacks-pc/):

As Bluestacks emulates Android, the default download path should be similar i.e. `/sdcard/Download` (or `/storage/sdcard/Download`)

Using a file explorer e.g ES explorer, **browse** the file structure until you come across the root folder, from there try locating the above path.

Now Bluestacks has an integrated Shared folder with Windows in the following paths:

`/storage/sdcard/windows/bstsharedfolder/`

or

`/sdcard/windows/bstsharedfolder`

In order to access your downloaded files in Windows explorer, you need to copy the contents of the download folder (`/sdcard/Download`) to the Bluestacks Shared folder (`/sdcard/windows/bstsharedfolder`) using ES file explorer.

Finally access the downloaded files from the PC via Windows explorer from this path:

`C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder`

**Remember to enable the option "Show hidden files and folders" in Windows explorer options**

Update

If you are unable to find bstfolder in its default Windows location [`C:\ ProgramData\ BlueStacks\ UserData\ SharedFolder` ], you can find their actual location from the Windows Registry.

1. Access the Windows Registry by going to Start >> Run and type in “regedit” and hit Enter. This opens up the Registry Editor.
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\SharedFolder`. Each of the numeric folders represents a shared folder, and their location is indicated in their Path String values.

You may have to [manually set the Bluestacks shared folder](https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/how-to-access-your-computers-files-in-bluestacks-on-windows.html) in the following way:

> - go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\SharedFolder`.
> - Create a new key here and rename it to the number following the previous key.
> - Inside the newly created key, right-click on the space on the right side and create a new String called “Name” by selecting New >> String.
>     Double-click on it and enter a value.
> - The value is the name of the folder as seen inside BlueStacks, additionally create a new `DWORD` Value by right-clicking on the blank
>     space and selecting New >> `DWORD` (32 Bit) Value and rename it as
>     **Writable**. Right-click on this newly created value and click Modify.
>     **Set the Value data field as 1** and select the base as Hexadecimal.
> - Create another String called “**Path**” and assign a value of the full path of the directory you want to include inside BlueStacks.
> - Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

Now you will be able to access BlueStacks files from Windows.

---

Update:

As mentioned by [Josh Davis](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/256013/josh-davis) if you can't find the path in newer Windows version, navigated to this path instead: `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\Engine\UserData\SharedFolder`

Comment: still shared folder empty

Comment: Please edit your question with clarification on what you're trying to achieve, right now its hard to guess what's happening, and also the above workaround is one of the most probable solution

Comment: my issue is that..whatever i download from bluestack i am not able to find it in my computer...

Comment: can you help me thorough this

Comment: Not that this is a help...but I have a co-worker that has the same problem since using Bluestacks 3. (Maybe it would be a plan to go back to Bluestacks 2 because of this...)

Comment: @Yosroel Agreed! perhaps this is the only way out

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is

> "You are not able to find your downloaded files which you have
>   downloaded over bluestacks"

You can move to this ----

`C:\ProgramData\Bluestacks\UserData\SharedFolder`

here you will find all your shared data

- First enable hidden files and folder to view program data folder

or you can  just send all files to desktop from bluestacks to view all your files and other stuff

hope this will help you...

Comment: i already checked this folder so many times..but it shows empty..

Comment: you can also install es explorer and choose send to windows this will help you

Comment: how to do that can you tell steps? i already installed es explorer

Answer (score 0):

Use the Media Manager to transfer files from Bluestacks to Windows. 
Here are the steps.

1. Click on *My Apps* tab.
2. Click on *System* app.
3. Click the Media Manager.
4. Long left mouse click on the file you want to transfer to Windows.
5. At the top click on *Export to Windows*.
6. Select a location in Windows and your file will be saved there.
7. In Windows browse to your save location and now you will have the file located there.

Answer (score 0):

My path as of 9/6/2018 in Windows 10 is:

C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks_bgp_kk\Engine\UserData\SharedFolder

ProgramData is a hidden file in windows 10.
In ES File Explorer I go to:

Home->Internal Storage->Windows->BstSharedFolder
[image: ES File Explorer]

Here are the same files in Windows File Explorer:
[image: Windows File Explorer]
Note the path.

I have BlueStacks 3 installed.
[image: BlueStacks Icon]